# 2 Views 1 Form in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I am having trouble articulating the exact issue I am facing, but I will try with a brief descriptions and code.

I am trying to add a feature to a simple existing app that allows the user to crop an uploaded image for an avatar. I do the file selection on the same view that allows the user to update their password and other various account options. The user submits that form which then renders the view for the cropping feature. The issue is that from the crop view, the submission fails because it fails validation of parameters from the previous form. Basically I would like the form to all be submitted at the same time but from two different views.

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :avatar,
                         :crop_x, :crop_y, :crop_w, :crop_h

  validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true

  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
  attr_accessor :crop_x, :crop_y, :crop_w, :crop_h
  after_update :crop_avatar

  def crop_avatar
    avatar.recreate_versions! if crop_x.present?
  end
end
```

I have tried several different things to remedy this. I am sure I am missing a fundamental concept. Any ideas?

**users_controller.rb**

```
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    if params[:user][:avatar].present?
      render 'crop'
    else
      sign_in @user
      redirect_to @user, notice: "Successfully updated user."
    end
  else
   render 'edit'
  end
end
```

**edit.html.erb**

```
<% provide(:title, "Edit user") %> 
<h1>Update your profile</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset3">
    <%= form_for @user, :html => {:multipart => true } do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

      <%= f.label :avatar %>
      <%= f.file_field :avatar %>

      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.text_field :email %>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password %>

      <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirm Password" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>

      <%= f.submit "Save changes", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

**crop.html.erb**

```
<% provide(:title, 'Crop Avatar') %>
<h1>Crop Avatar</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset3">
    <%= image_tag @user.avatar_url(:large), id: "cropbox" %>

    <h4>Preview</h4>
    <div style="width:100px; height:100px; overflow:hidden">
      <%= image_tag @user.avatar.url(:large), :id => "preview" %>
    </div>

    <%= form_for @user do |f| %>
      <% %w[x y w h].each do |attribute| %>
        <%= f.hidden_field "crop_#{attribute}" %>
      <% end %>
      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "Crop" %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you try to create several hidden inputs in crop.html.erb mirroring the ones in edit.html.erb, and populate them with @user properties?

Comment: Thanks for the response. This worked. I am concerned that this might not be best practice, because the page's source then contains password information. What do you think about that?

Comment: I need more info. Regarding password... do you use Devise for authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have 2 views for one action. On a second thought why do you need it anyways, i mean you are rendering crop only when params[:user][:avatar] is present and that will be called only when you'll submit your edit.html.erb template. I think what you can do is have another method in controller with name crop and there update user's avatar with the dimention's specified.